Solution to the previous contest question
Some weeks ago I posted a question: Solving the calculus problem using intuition and not using pen

Given function $$f(x)=\frac{x^4}{(x-2)(x-1)}$$ and its third derivative is $$\frac{-k}{(x-2)^4}+\frac{6}{(x-1)^4}$$ what will be the numerical value of $k$?

This is a mock problem for the isi bstat-bmath exam held in India.
The creative solution according to my sources is :
For any polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ and its derivative $p’(x)$ the roots of both the polynomial will be same .
Also we can see that if that there are any repeated roots then also the derivative up to $n-1$ order will have the same roots for eg- $(x-k)^n$ and $(n.(x-k)^{n-1})$ will have the same roots.
We can see that $f(0)=0$ so $x=0$ will be a solution . Now if we put this value into the third derivative we will get $0$ only as the derivative will also have the same root.
So $f’’’(0)= \frac{-k}{(0-2)^4}+\frac{6}{(0-1)^4}= 0$ using the above theorem . And from this we conclude $k=\fbox{96}$. This was the idea of the creative solution I was looking for in my previous question . Thank you.
If the given solution still lacks some proper proof then it would be very helpful if anyone adds some improvements to the given answer.

But there are two things

$f$ is not polynomial
your idea possibly is wrong, consider any quadratic equation with distinct roots, your idea already is not correct. However, when the root multiplicity $>1$, then both the polynomial and its derivative will still have this root.

So if you want to use this, you need to show that "2" still holds for rational function first.

btw a more appropriate method would be partial fraction.

The average of the roots of any polynomial is equal to the average of the roots of its derivative. This is not the same as the roots themselves being equal.

Why is this tagged as [tag:recreational-mathematics]?

This has been tagged contest-math. Which contest did this question come from?

I am sorry for tagging it as recreational maths . It is a contest problem. So in contests we cannot actually verify all the above mentioned points in detail due to time pressure. So what would be the key observation to solve the problem in an efficient way? This mentioned way is the only appropriate way to solve the problem in an examination hall . I hope that you understand why I posted this question @AngaeMT .

There is no question in your post.

@RedFive this is a mock problem for the isi bstat-bmath exam held in India .

@AnneBauval I have posted this question few weeks earlier and donot know how to refer to the same problem in this post so I re wrote the problem and posted it

Please do not repost. Instead, edit your previous post to improve it and get it reopened, so that you can post your self-answer on it.

Is the above editing good @AnneBauval?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You are right that the value of $f’’’(0)=0$ but the reasoning seems a bit misleading. If $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ then:
$$ f^{(n)} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (^n_i)g^{(i)}h^{(n-i)}$$
If we look at this function when $x=0$ and let $n=3$ then there are only up to third derivatives in this expression and because the zeroth, first, second, and third derivatives of $x^4$ are zero, every term in this sum will be zero. Hence, $f’’’(0) =0$.

Thank you . Now I understood what I was missing in my answer. Thank you very much @Nic.
